# Why my Android emulator shows black screen?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a Xamarin.Forms project, but the Android emulation doesn't work, the only emulation that I can do is the UWP.
It doesn't have any compiler errors, but shows black so I enabled Hyper V Emulation in the Windows features, and also turned it on in the BIOS, Again, nothing.
Now instead of turning to a black screen, it does not compile (I repeat, only this happens on Android).
Sometime It told me about HAXM and that I don't have an Intel processor, that could be?

**Edit** 
I don't know if it affects, but
My specifications are:.
-AMD Dual Core E-450
-6 GB RAM
-500GB Total Storage
-400GB available
-Windows 10

Comment: HAXM is based on Intel's VT/VT-x/vmx virtualization technology, if you have a AMD Ryzen (AMD-V, SVM virtualization technology) you will need to use Windows Hypervisor Platform (WHPX) and make sure that you are using using the latest emulator, i.e. right now it is `Android emulator version 28.0.0.0`

Comment: @SushiHangover And how to change it to WHPX?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration#accel-vm

Comment: @SushiHangover I have updated it, please, check it

Comment: E-450 is *really* underpowered for AMD-V and running the Android Emulator within WHPX, I would assume it will eventually run but you could be waiting a long time... something I would be is to try and run the `emulator` executable from the cmd line (passing in the required options to start the AVD and include the `-verbose` option) to watch the output for errors/progress

Comment: You could just use a USB-connected Android device for debugging....

Comment: @SushiHangover I only have an iPhone :s